# How can I get the substring after a specifc word and on another word in a string

Tags: c#, .net, substring, indexof, between

Say I have the string "Old Macdonald had a farm and on".
I want to get the substring "had a farm".
I want to get anything after the work "Macdonald" and up to the word "farm"

So the constants in the string are:

"Macdonald" - which I don't want included in the substring

"farm" - which I want included and the end word in the substring

I've been trying to incorporate the indexof etc. functions but can't seem to get it to work

Comment: you can use regex. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) ... Or you can split the whole string into sub-string separated by white space.. and take strings after "MacDonald" till "farm" and concate them.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`RegEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) with `(?<=Macdonald\s).*(?=\sand)`

**Explanation**

- **Positive Lookbehind** `(?<=Macdonald\s)`

  - `Macdonald` matches the characters `Macdonald` literally
  - `\s` matches any whitespace character
- `.*` matches any character (except for line terminators)

  - `*` **Quantifier** — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- **Positive Lookahead** `(?=\sand)`

  - `\s` matches any whitespace character and matches the characters `and` literally

**Example**

```
var input = "Old Macdonald had a farm and on";
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=Macdonald\s).*(?=\sand)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var match = regex.Match(input);
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No farms for you");
}
```

**Output**

```
had a farm
```

---

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NsMOyw)

Comment: I would have upvoted this answer, but I have upvoted couple of your answers recently and there are chances that now my votes will considered as "Targeted votes" :D

Comment: @Amit Hah, target away :)

Comment: I was about to write same answer. Anyways +1. Could you please explain about lookbehind positive and lookahead positive so that OP would understand regex in better way.

Comment: Unfortunately the application I'm using does not allow me to use regex or console so haven't been able to test this. I have been able to do it the regular way thanx.

Comment: @AusGamer see my answer

Comment: @Amit - I don't think that would happen. Jon Skeet would have been banned years ago if it did.

Comment: @Enigmativity interesting, however one of my colleagues had such indecent recently! I guess SO have some smart way to detect genuine votes.

Comment: @Enigmativity I m talking about this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed)

Answer (score 0):

As I've mentioned in my comment, I would recommend using of Regex (the way TheGeneral suggested). But there is another way to do it.

**Adding it as workaround**

```
        string input = "Old Macdonald had a farm and on";
        List<string> words = input.Split(" ".ToCharArray()).ToList();
        string finalString = "";

        int indexOfMac = words.IndexOf("Macdonald");
        int indexOfFarm = words.IndexOf("farm");


        if (indexOfFarm != -1 && indexOfMac != -1 &&  //if word is not there in string, index will be '-1' 
            indexOfMac < indexOfFarm)  //checking if 'macdonald' comes before 'farm' or not

        {
            //looping from Macdonald + 1 to farm, and make final string
            for(int i = indexOfMac + 1; i <= indexOfFarm; i++)
            {
                finalString += words[i] + " ";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            finalString = "No farms for you";
        }

        Console.WriteLine(finalString);
```

Comment: Better to hold index of those string in int variable rather than using magic string everytime

Answer (score 0):

You can use IndexOf() and Substring() as

```
string input = "Old Macdonald had a farm and on";
int pos=input.IndexOf("Macdonald");
if(pos > -1){
  string s2=input.Substring(pos);
  string second="farm";
  int secLen=second.Length;
  int pos2=s2.IndexOf(second);
  if(pos2 > -1){
    Console.WriteLine("Substring: {0}", s2.Substring(0,pos2+secLen));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And of course Linq can't be excluded from the list of solutions:

```
string SearchString = "Old Macdonald had a farm and on";
string fromPattern = "Macdonald";
string toPattern = "farm";

string result = string.Join(" ", SearchString
                      .Split((char)32)
                      .SkipWhile(s => s != fromPattern)
                      .Skip(1)
                      .TakeWhile(s => s != toPattern)
                      .Append(toPattern));
```